# How to change whole layout of a div without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So, I'm doing a project on **React** and I have this `div` tag which is a container that consists of information portrayed in this first [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs9hc.jpg). Then what I would like to do is **within that div without having the page refreshed** change the display into this second [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrbo6.jpg). It is like a card stacking on each other. I have no idea what keywords to search on google so I couldn't find any examples to do this.

Here's my `html and css` code for my div in the `first image`.

`HTML`

```
<div className={styles.showTicketBox}>
   <div className={styles.showTicketBox1}>
      <div className={styles.userEligibleTickets}>
         <p>Your Eligible Tickets</p>
         <h3 style={tokenContent}>0 Ticket(s)</h3>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.userDepositedTickets}>
         <p>Your Deposited Tickets</p>
         <h3 style={tokenContent}>0 Ticket(s)</h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div className={styles.showTicketBox2}>
      <div className={styles.userWinningTickets}>
         <p>Your Winning Tickets</p>
         <h3 style={tokenContent}>0 Ticket(s)</h3>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.userTicketsAllo}>
         <p>Your Allocation</p>
         <h3 style={tokenContent}>0 SHI</h3>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.showTicketBox{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    .showTicketBox1{
        width: auto;
        height:auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .showTicketBox2{
        width: auto;
        height:auto;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you're using React, you can have one component for each case, and show one or the other based on a condition (that's pretty much how React works and what it was made for, I think)

Comment: @JeremyThille Hmm okay I will try doing that which is by doing each page using component. Thank you for the advice!